# Connecting two queries into one

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I got such two queries:

```
SELECT
count (C.CaseDetailsId) as [Z telefonem]
,U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName as [Windykator]
from CaseDetails as C
join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
join Users as U on C.UserId = U.UserId
where D.DebtorDetailsId in 
(SELECT DebtorDetailsId from DebtorPhone 
where (IsValid = 'True') or (IsDefault = 'True')) 
and C.CaseStatusId <> 2 and C.CaseStatusId <> 6 group by U.FirstName,U.LastName
```

e

and

```
SELECT
count (CaseDetailsId) as [Beztel]
,U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName as [Windykator]
from CaseDetails as C
join Users as U on C.UserId = U.UserId
where
C.CaseStatusId <> 2 and C.CaseStatusId <> 6 group by U.FirstName,U.LastName
```

I need to group the results of those two into 1 table so I suppose it would be best to connect them but I have no idea how to do it.

The query has to count rows in two cases
1) overall
2) where exists a specified row in another table

So in general -> I need to count number of cases (CaseDetailsId) for every employeer (Users) with and without phone number (DebtorPhones)

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you one record set from two queries using union. You can add insert statement above select to insert into your required table.

```
SELECT Count (C.casedetailsid)        AS [Z telefonem], 
               U.firstname + ' ' + U.lastname AS [Windykator] 
        FROM   casedetails AS C 
               JOIN debtordetails AS D 
                 ON C.casedetailsid = D.casedetailsid 
               JOIN users AS U 
                 ON C.userid = U.userid 
        WHERE  D.debtordetailsid IN (SELECT debtordetailsid 
                                     FROM   debtorphone 
                                     WHERE  ( isvalid = 'True' ) 
                                             OR ( isdefault = 'True' )) 
               AND C.casestatusid <> 2 
               AND C.casestatusid <> 6 
        GROUP  BY U.firstname, 
                  U.lastname  
    Union
    SELECT Count (casedetailsid)          AS [Z telefonem], 
           U.firstname + ' ' + U.lastname AS [Windykator] 
    FROM   casedetails AS C 
           JOIN users AS U 
             ON C.userid = U.userid 
    WHERE  C.casestatusid <> 2 
           AND C.casestatusid <> 6 
    GROUP  BY U.firstname, 
              U.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pratik Kaje not really. It shows 2 columns only - [Z tel] and [Windykator]

I tested a bit and ended with such query:

```
SELECT
[Windykator]
,[Beztel]
,[Z telefonem]
from
(SELECT
count (C.CaseDetailsId) as [Z telefonem]
,NULL as [Beztel]
,NULL as [Windykator]
from CaseDetails as C
join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
join Users as U on C.UserId = U.UserId
where D.DebtorDetailsId in 
(SELECT DebtorDetailsId from DebtorPhone 
where (IsValid = 'True') or (IsDefault = 'True')) 
and C.CaseStatusId <> 2 and C.CaseStatusId <> 6
group by U.FirstName, U.LastName
UNION ALL
SELECT
NULL
,count (CaseDetailsId) as [Beztel]
,NULL
from CaseDetails as C
join Users as U on C.UserId = U.UserId
where
C.CaseStatusId <> 2 and C.CaseStatusId <> 6
group by U.FirstName, U.LastName
UNION ALL
SELECT
NULL
,NULL
,U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName
from CaseDetails as C
join Users as U on C.UserId = U.UserId
where
C.CaseStatusId <> 2 and C.CaseStatusId <> 6
group by U.FirstName, U.LastName
) as x
```

Almost perfectly however the results are not grouped. So it shows results with

```
NULLS NULLS [Bez tel]
NULLS [Z tel] NULLS
[Windykator] NULLS NULLS
```